# How to solve reCAPTCHA v2 with obfuscated code?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

I'm using the DeathByCaptcha service to solve the reCAPTCHA challenge on a specific page. After solving the CAPTCHA, I obtain the token and I'm trying to input it into a  element.

However, I'm facing an issue. There's no submit button available to submit the token. Furthermore, I noticed that the  isn't nested inside a  tag, but directly within an .

Here's a simplified example of the page structure:

```
<iframe>
    <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response"></textarea>
</iframe>
```

[image]

I'm using JavaScript to insert the token into the `<textarea>`, but I can't figure out how to submit this token as there is no submit button present.

How could I resolve this? Is there a way to trigger form submission via JavaScript even without the presence of a submit button?

Comment: Look for a callback function that you can pass a token to. With v2, there has to be one iirc. Then you'll execute javascript and pass the token into that method

Comment: Each method is named after a letter of the alphabet, which heightens the complexity in deciphering their purpose and operation.

Comment: do you have a url I can look at?

Comment: sorry for the delay

Comment: Ah, it does have a callback function, but they've guarded it from being accessed directly. I'll see if I can figure out how to access it, but I won't guarantee I know an answer